# Как создать иконочный шрифт из своих иконок?

Tags: html, svg, шрифты, иконки

Есть нарисованные дизайнером иконки - как из них создать иконочный шрифт?

Comment: Зачем в 2021 году создавать иконочный шрифт? А в остальном, точно так же как и неиконочный.

Comment: В смысле зачем?)
К примеру, есть дизайн макет с кучей иконок. Никакой плагин не использовался. Подключать везде через тег img или svg не вариант.

Comment: https://www.irigoyen.dev/blog/2021/02/17/stop-using-icon-fonts/ именно img/svg и вариант.

Comment: Один из вариантов https://youtu.be/YDKskOH5sSw

Comment: https://fontello.com/ можете здесь выбрать один из готовых

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, никто не отменял уже готовых иконсетов, таких как [fontello.com](https://fontello.com/) или [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/).

А если у вас совсем уж уникальные значки отрисованы, то можно создать иконочный шрифт на основе svg-картинок - [видео](https://youtu.be/YDKskOH5sSw).

Comment: Ну так дизайнеры не всегда юзают готовые иконосеты.

Comment: Верно, поэтому в ответе приведена ссылка на видео, как из иконок создать svg-шрифт. Конечно, это лишь один вариант из многих.